# How to Add Break Plus Space to Code \r\n\r\n

Tags: return, space, carriage-return

I am trying add line break plus a space ( ). I know I can do

> \r\n\r\n

to get the line break but how do i also add a space. I know in HTML i can do this

`<br>&nbsp;`

But how would I achieve \r\n\r\n + Space. What characters do i need to add to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: give an example of what you're trying to achieve, and a sample of your code

Answer (score 0):

you can't do a return (`\r`) in html.

You'll need to use Javascript if you want to remove content from an `element` then replace it with other content.